# How to reset values in radio button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I choose the first (second or last) option, the rest option will be disabled and all values in the selected option will be enabled. However, my code worked in a wrong direction. Please help me to solve this.

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bT79r/2/)</kbd>**

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="company_vehicle" />Company Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="company_vehicle">
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />Company Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="hiring_vehicle" />Hiring Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="hiring_vehicle">
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="car" />Car</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="bus" />Bus</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="taxi" />Taxi</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="taxi">
<td>
        <input type="checkbox" />Taxi</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var rbt_vehicle = $("input[name=vehicle]");

$(rbt_vehicle).on('change', function (e) {
var optionSelected = $("option:checked", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
//alert(valueSelected);
$("#" + valueSelected).find('input[type="text"]').val('').addClass("readOnly").attr('disabled', true);
$("#" + valueSelected).find(':checkbox,:radio').prop('checked', false).addClass("readOnly").attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
var rbt_vehicle = $("input[name=vehicle]");

$(rbt_vehicle).on('change', function (e) {
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    $('#' + valueSelected).find(':text').prop('disabled', false).val('').removeClass('readonly').closest('tr').siblings('tr.set_width').find(':text').prop('disabled', true).addClass('readonly');
    $('#' + valueSelected).find(':checkbox,:radio').prop('disabled', false).closest('tr').siblings('tr.set_width').find(':checkbox,:radio').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Please note that you need to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to set the state of form elements.

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bT79r/6/)**

Comment: Thank you for your code but It doesn't work with Taxi option (when I select the Taxi option, two `textbox`s must be disabled).

Comment: Did you check my demo? It's working as what you've described.

Comment: As your demo http://jsfiddle.net/bT79r/6/ - Please select Taxi option, the textboxs were not be disabled... Am I correct?

Comment: What textbox? I thought `taxi` textbox should be enabled when you click `taxi` radio?

Comment: **@Felix**: http://upanh.biz/images/2014/05/09/UntitlednRV3J.png - Please have a look on it, the result is in the left side. This shows what I mean.

Comment: Then if the textbox is enabled then if I click on it, what should happen?

Comment: These textboxs are only be enabled when you click on each radio button.

Comment: Well, I completely lost here. I thought that the taxi textbox is only enabled when you select taxi radio button right? That's exactly what my demo is doing.

Comment: That's fine. When you click on the radio option, the textbox in this option is be enabled. I'm still waiting for the best answer here :-)

Comment: **@Felix**: Whenever you update the code, please let me know about that. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name=vehicle]").click(function(ev){

rowID = $(this).val();
rowSelector = "#"+rowID;



$(".active").removeClass("active");
$(rowSelector).addClass("active");

$.each($(".set_width"),function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
      $(this).find("input").prop("disabled",true);  
    }
    else{
        $(this).find("input").removeProp("disabled");
    }
});



});
```

I am sorry I cannot fork through your JSFiddle. I had to edit your code. But basically, here is how I solved the problem.

First, I analyzed your DOM ties in the IDs. Everytime a radio button is clicked, I get its value. I append it to a Hashtag for an ID selector since you built the next row that way.

Next, I am trying to remove all classes with "active", and set the selected row to "active" class.

Now, the next loop will put all "active" rows enabled, and all "non active" class rows disabled in inputs.

Comment: Wait. A glitch just appeared for the other radio boxes. I have to change to code a bit.

Comment: Using `.attr()` to set boolean attributes is generally not a good idea. You should try using `.prop()` instead.

Comment: You could directly select: `$("input[name=vehicle]")`

Comment: You shouldn't use `removeProp` to remove the disabled property. As per jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/): `Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected`. And also `.prop("disabled","true");` is not correct as it leads the OP to believe `.prop("disabled","false");` would work - which it wouldn't. It should be a boolean: `.prop("disabled",true);`

Comment: Then what should I use to remove native properties? Please enlighten me.

Comment: Sorry, so the inverse of `.prop("disabled",true);` which would be `.prop("disabled",false);`

Answer (score 1):

this should do what you need,

HTML:

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="company_vehicle" />Company Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="company_vehicle">
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="child" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" />Company Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="hiring_vehicle" />Hiring Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="hiring_vehicle">
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="child"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="car" class="child" />Car</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="bus" class="child" />Bus</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="taxi" />Taxi</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="taxi">
<td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" />Taxi</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var rbt_vehicle = $("input[name=vehicle]");

$(rbt_vehicle).on('change', function (e) {
var optionSelected = $("option:checked", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
    $('input.child').addClass("readOnly").attr('disabled', true);

    // if you want to clear disabled values...
    $('input[type="text"].child').val('');
    $('input[type="radio"].child').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[type="checkbox"].child').prop('checked', false);

    $("#" + valueSelected).find('input.child').removeClass('readOnly').attr('disabled', false);

});

$('input.child').addClass("readOnly").attr('disabled', true);
```

checkout this running example

http://jsfiddle.net/CEuZd/

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. However, as I've checked, I am not allowed to edit the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer please let me know if something goes wrong or you have another way to make it shorter or more understandable :-)

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/H37wq/1/)</kbd>**

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="company_vehicle" />Company Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="company_vehicle">
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />Company Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="hiring_vehicle" />Hiring Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="hiring_vehicle">
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="car" />Car</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="bus" />Bus</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="taxi" />Taxi</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="taxi">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />Taxi</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var rbt_vehicle = $("input[name=vehicle]");

// Set disabled state all values as default
$('.set_width input[type="text"]').addClass("readonly").attr('disabled', true);
$('.set_width input[type="radio"]').addClass("readonly").attr('disabled', true);
$('.set_width input[type="checkbox"]').addClass("readonly").attr('disabled', true);

$(rbt_vehicle).on('change', function (e) {
var valueSelected = this.value;

$('.set_width input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', valueSelected === 'taxi').addClass('readonly').val('');

$('#' + valueSelected).find(':text').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('readonly').closest('tr').siblings('tr.set_width').find(':text').prop('disabled', true).val('').addClass('readonly');
$('#' + valueSelected).find(':checkbox,:radio').prop('disabled', false).closest('tr').siblings('tr.set_width').find(':checkbox,:radio').prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);

});
```